# Is there one Rack app instance per HTTP request?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, facebook, sinatra, rack

I'm building a [Facebook app called Lovers](http://apps.facebook.com/mylovers/), using a [Sinatra app on Heroku](http://docs.heroku.com/rack#sinatra). It's running on Ruby 1.9.2 on [Heroku's bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack](http://docs.heroku.com/bamboo).

It's a [modular Sinatra app](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps), and in the [Lovers source code](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/loversapp.com/blob/master/lib/lovers/lib/lovers/application.rb), I'm giving each instance of the Sinatra app (`Lovers::Application`) an instance of `Facebook::Application`:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Lovers::Application < Sinatra::Base
  attr_reader :facebook

  def initialize(app=nil)
    @facebook = Facebook::Application.new(
      Lovers::Conf.fb_app_id,
      Lovers::Conf.fb_app_secret,
      Lovers::Conf.fb_canvas_name)
    super(app)
  end
  # ...
end
```

That way, you can do `Lovers.application.facebook` to access the `Facebook::Application` instance from anywhere within the `Lovers` module, say from `Lovers::User`.

Does this make sense, or should I just have all instances of `Lovers::Application` (if there's ever more than one) share the same `Facebook::Application` instance, i.e., `Lovers.facebook`. That's what we're doing for Redis: `Lovers.redis`, which makes sense to me. I guess I'm leaning toward changing it to the latter, but I want to make sure before I change it. What do you think?

Finally, is there one instance of `Lovers::Application` per HTTP request?

UPDATE:

I read up on [Heroku Dynos](http://heroku.com/how/dynos). Apparently, each dyno (process) runs an instance of `Lovers::Application`. So, after reading about [sharing a global variable among processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564959/how-can-perl-share-global-variables-in-parallel-processing/1565001#1565001), I think that means that if I define a class variable `@@hit_count` in the `Lovers::Application` class, it will have different values depending on which dyno receives the request, assuming I increment `@@hit_count` every time the home page is requested, i.e.:

```
  @@hit_count = 0

  get "/" do
    @@hit_count += 1
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Finally, is there one instance of Lovers::Application per HTTP request?"

There's one instance per process/dyno.

"it will have different values depending on which dyno receives the request, assuming I increment @@hit_count every time the home page is requested"

yes, if you need global state you have to keep the state outside of your process/dyno. There are many different ways to do this, and which you choose will depend on the details of your app and your traffic levels. If you don't get a lot of traffic you can do something as simple as keeping it in your database. You can do atomic increments in postgres or mysql for something like hit_count. However, this approach may become a bottleneck if you have a lot of traffic.

Comment: Can you elaborate on some possible ideas for keeping the state outside the process? I'm trying to come up with a good solution at the moment that avoids storing the value in the DB - something that wont fall down in a high traffic environment. thanks